# How can I add SqlParameters without knowing the name / type?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am creating a DB wrapper and am in the need of adding SQL paramters to my stament however I do not know the parameter names or type, how can this be done? I have seen many other libraries do this...

I just want the order of values to be mapped to the stored procedure...I thought the following code would work:

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcName, params object[] args)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // inserting params like this does not work...
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Insert(i, args[0]);
    }

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    return dt;
}
```

Any ideas of how to accomplish this? Note: I know there are other libraries such as the Enterprise Library that already does this, but I'm in a situation where that won't help...

Thanks.

Comment: If you want your code to appear, all the '<' and  the '>' in your code must be replaced with < or >

Comment: I dont have any greater than / less than signs...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Comment: Link to another stackoverflow post is not very useful.