# Retrieve input and output parameters for SQL stored procs and functions?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, parameters, user-defined-functions

For a given SQL stored proc or function, I'm trying to obtain its input and output parameters, where applicable, in a Winforms app I'm creating to browse objects and display their parameters and other attributes.

So far I've discovered the SQL system function **object_definition**, which takes a given *sysobjects.id* and returns the text of that object; also discovered via search [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server#33781) which describes extracting the parameters in the context of a app using the ADO.NET method **DeriveParameters** in conjunction with some caching for better performance; and for good measure found some helpful system stored procs from this earlier post on [Hidden Features of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server).

I'm leaning towards implementing the **DeriveParameters** method in my C# app, since parsing the output of **object_definition** seems messy, and I haven't found a hidden feature in that post so far that would do the trick.

Is **DeriveParameters** applicable to both functions and stored procs for purposes of retreiving their parameters, and if so, could someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select
PARAMETER_NAME,
DATA_TYPE,
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
PARAMETER_MODE,
NUMERIC_PRECISION,
NUMERIC_SCALE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
where specific_name = @chvProcName
order by ordinal_position
```

look for PARAMETER_MODE it will have a value of OUT

Got this info from [here](http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-sqlserver/217882-information_schema-parameters.html)

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful; if I don't see any responses specific to the DeriveParameters method in .NET, I'll award you the answer.