# How can I determine if a stored procedure needs a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, massive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I retrieve a list of parameters from a stored procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

I'm using Massive to create a generic stored procedure executor. Basically, I have a function that takes the name of a procedure, and a variable number of parameters. Then, I blindly attempt to execute that stored procedure with the passed parameters and either return the result, or handle errors.

My question is: is there a way for me to determine what parameters the stored procedure expects, before calling it?

Comment: Look at the definition of the SP in SQLMS.

Comment: Have you looked at sys.parameters JOIN sys.procedures on object_id?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ProcedureName = pr.Name,
    ParameterName = p.Name,
    Typename = ty.name 
FROM 
    sys.parameters p
INNER JOIN 
    sys.procedures pr ON p.object_id = pr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON p.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
WHERE   
    pr.Name = '.....'   -- put your stored procedure name here
ORDER BY 
    p.Name, p.parameter_id
```

This will inspect the system catalog views and show you the parameters and their type for a given procedure.

The system catalog view contains additional info (like whether the parameter has a default value and if so, what it is; whether it's a XML parameter and so forth) - check out the [MSDN documentation for all details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx)!

Comment: So you mean I should execute this with massive, and expand the result into a list to use, right?

Comment: @roviuser: this SQL query will get you the info you need - how you fetch that, is totally up to you ...

Comment: +1 You might also include things like whether the param `is_output` and optional (`has_default_value` = 1). `is_readonly` might also be useful in 2008+ if TVPs are in use.

Comment: Thanks. Your WHERE clause should be `pr.Name`.