# how to get stored procedure parameters count using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedure with **"same name"** but different functionality in different database.

Suppose I have two database named DB1 & DB2. In DB1 stored procedure contains 7 parameteres and DB2 contains 11 parameters.

So how can i get stored procedure parameteres count using C#. By using Count I can add condition for both different databases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve a list of parameters from a stored procedure in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am using session for getting connection string.using nhibernate ORM

Answer (score 0):

Following links will help you,

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043832/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092408-1.aspx

http://adamprescott.net/2012/09/21/sqlcommandbuilder-deriveparameters/

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/getting-the-list-of-parameters/

any help let me know...............