# Get parameters for a ADO.NET CommandText

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Is there any way (maybe even in ADO.NET) to get a list of the parameters of a CommandText?

That is to say, given the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES(@value1, @value2)
```

Is there any way to know that the query parameters are value1, value2? Or should I have to parse the query on my own to find them (of course '@' syntax may change from one db engine to other...)?

Clarification:

I want to know the parameters name and the order in the query before having to fill the command parameters dictionary.

Comment: I remember I needed this too, unfortunately ended up with parsing it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SqlParameterCollection.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get that information.

So you can do like

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table test values(@value1, @value2)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";

        int count = cmd.Parameters.Count; // you get the parameter count
```

You as well get the name of parameter using the parameter collection like

```
        string p1 = cmd.Parameters[0].ParameterName;
        string p2 = cmd.Parameters[1].ParameterName;
```

Not exactly sure what you mean by *parameters order in the query*

Comment: I think the OP means they have a query string and they want to determine the parameters from the string.

Comment: @juharr, possibly yes looks like. well he can store the `SqlParameterCollection` to a variable and later can use that to get the information ... else parse the string. Thanks for pointing. if the answer anyway doesn't helps then I won't keep it.

Comment: @juharr is right I want the parameters name from the query text to ensure that when the Parameters are filled, there is no mismatch in number/ order/name (you know, Oracle issues).

Comment: @danijepg, then misinterpret here ... BTW no other way than parsing the query string which will be ugly if it's a bugger query.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is a stored procedure, you can use `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameter`s (see  [How can I retrieve a list of parameters from a stored procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)). However that unfortunately only works for `CommandType=StoredProcedure`

In SQL Server 2012 (and above) you can use `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260.aspx)

Doesn't seem like there is any alternative for lower versions other than parsing the SQL query text directly (regex, or possibly using the SQLDOM that ships with SSDT (or via nuget): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2013/04/04/using-the-transactsql-scriptdom-parser-to-get-statement-counts/ )

Edit: simple F# example of finding parameters using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom` nuget:

```
#r "Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom"

open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic
open Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom

let query = @"select * from dbo.Customers where FirstName=@FirstName"

let parser = new TSql120Parser(true)
let errors : ref<IList<ParseError>> = ref(null)

let frag = parser.Parse(new StringReader(query), errors) // the actual work

frag.ScriptTokenStream
|> Seq.filter (fun f -> f.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.Variable)
|> Seq.iter (fun t -> (printfn "Type = %A; Name = %s" t.TokenType t.Text))
```

outputs

```
Type = Variable; Name = @FirstName
```

...however if the script involves temporary variables you can easily get false positives, eg:

```
declare @temp nvarchar(50) = @FirstName
select * from dbo.Customers where FirstName=@temp
```

...finds @temp twice, *and* @FirstName